# Json parsing from a php script

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I am developing an android application which has an access to a php script and parse the result returned by the code php.
The code php connects to the base and return a result.
The problem is that I get an error : Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value

Thanks for your help :)
Java code :

```
 public class ville extends Activity {
    TextView txt;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        LinearLayout rootLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());  
        txt = new TextView(getApplicationContext());  
        rootLayout.addView(txt);  
        setContentView(rootLayout);  

        // DÃ©finir le texte et appeler la fonction de connexion.  
        txt.setText("Connexion..."); 
        // Appeler la mÃ©thode pour rÃ©cupÃ©rer les donnÃ©es JSON
        txt.setText(getServerData(strURL)); 
    }

    // Mettre l'adresse du script PHP
    // Attention localhost ou 127.0.0.1 ne fonctionnent pas. Mettre l'adresse IP local.
    public static final String strURL = "http://192.168.1.2/www/nouveaudossier/ville.php";

    private String getServerData(String returnString) {
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";
        // Envoyer la requÃªte au script PHP.
        // Script PHP : $sql=mysql_query("select * from tblVille where Nom_ville like '".$_REQUEST['ville']."%'");
        // $_REQUEST['ville'] sera remplacÃ© par L dans notre exemple.
        // Ce qui veut dire que la requÃªte enverra les villes commenÃ§ant par la lettre L
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Nom_ville","L"));

        // Envoie de la commande http
        try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(strURL);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }

        // Convertion de la requÃªte en string
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        // Parse les donnÃ©es JSON
        try{
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                 JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                 // Affichage ID_ville et Nom_ville dans le LogCat

                                Log.i("log_tag","ID_ville: "+json_data.getInt("ID_ville")+

                                         ", Nom_ville: "+json_data.getString("Nom_ville")

                                 );

                                 // Résultats de la requête

                                 returnString += "\n\t" + jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                             }

                         }catch(JSONException e){

                             Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());

                         }

                         return returnString;

                     }

                 }
```

php code :

```
<?php
  mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
  mysql_select_db("bdVille");
  $sql=mysql_query("select * from tblVille where Nom_ville like '".$_REQUEST['ville']."%'");
  while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
  $output[]=$row;
  print(json_encode($output));
  mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: more info? what's the full stack trace, what's the data you're parsing, and what libraries are you using?

Comment: How are we supposed to determine what went wrong if you do not give us the code and your exact input?

Comment: You're receiving HTML probably instead of json. that's what it says there at least. So you gotta fix your php output first.

Answer (score 1):

ok, probably you are missing the content type header in php script, add the following line to the php script.

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```